# Doctrine: DQL query without specifying class fully qualified name (FQN)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

Is there a way to write DQL queries without specifying the fully qualified name of the class?

Is there a way to create the following query:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    'SELECT i
     FROM Company\AccountingBundle\Entity\Invoice i
     WHERE i.id = :id'
)->setParameter('id', 1)
    ->getResult();
```

Like this :

```
use Company\AccountingBundle\Entity\Invoice;
....

return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    'SELECT i
     FROM Invoice i
     WHERE i.id = :id'
)->setParameter('id', 1)
    ->getResult();
```

Or something similar. I really would avoid to set the full FQN in the DQL.

But I didn't find any "setClass" or another method to do this.

**EDIT FOR CONTEXT**

In fact, it is a Symfony project and the query is inside in a Repository class. I have a Doctrine XML definition of the entity, an entity and the entity repository also defined in the XML, but I always need to explicitly define the FQN, Any ideas?

Comment: You can use string concatenation: 
`$work_class="Company\AccountingBundle\Entity\Invoice";
return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    'SELECT i
     FROM ' . $work_class . ' i
     WHERE i.id = :id'
)->setParameter('id', 1)
    ->getResult();`

Comment: Off the top of my head, build your query string with heredoc or through `sprintf` and just pass `Invoice::class` for the placeholder value.

Comment: An alternative would be to use repositories, as a repository is always tied to an entity so you don't need to explicitly state them. But I don't know the state of your application or the requirements, so this would take research on your end.

Comment: @El_Vanja thanks for your comment and you are right, I didn't explain the context! My bad. In fact, it is a Symfony project and the query is inside in a Repository class. I have a Doctrine XML definition of the entity, an entity and the entity repository also defined in the XML, but I always need to explicitly define the FQN, Any ideas?

Comment: Did you take a look at [alias](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#alias) parameter in your Doctrine configuration? An official example [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-entities-outside-of-a-bundle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Doctrine offers a way to alias entity namespaces to simpler, shorter names to be used in DQL queries or for Repository access.

You can set the **alias** of the entity namespace inside the Doctrine config of .yaml

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        Company:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Company/AccountingBundle/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Company\AccountingBundle\Entity'
            alias: AC
```

Then in the DQL, you can use "**AC:Invoice**":

```
return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
  'SELECT i
  FROM AC:Invoice i
  WHERE i.id = :id'
  )->setParameter('id', 1)
  ->getResult();
```

References

[Symfony bundle Mapping Configuration](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-bundle/en/2.2/configuration.html#mapping-configuration)

[Symfony Doctrine ORM Configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#alias)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your repository class extends `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`

Have you tried something like?

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
       ->createQuery('SELECT i FROM '.$this->getEntityName().' i where i.id = :id')
       ->setParameter('id',1)
       ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Doctrine way would be to use entity repositories. If your entity is configured so that it's tied to a repository, e.g.:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=InvoiceRepository::class)
 */
class Invoice
```

then in that repository, if you utilize a query builder, that entity is [automatically tied to the query](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-the-query-builder):

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i') // 'i' is just an alias here
    ->where('i.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $id);
```

To see all the options it offers, you can read more on the query builder [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html).

---

Quick alternatives (not including Doctrine functionalities), which I'll leave here for demonstrative purposes:

**1. Using `sprintf`**

```php
$q = sprintf('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id = :id', Invoice::class);

return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery($q)
    ->setParameter('id', 1)
    ->getResult();
```

**2. Using `HEREDOC` syntax**

```php
$entity = Invoice::class;
$q = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM {$entity}
    WHERE id = :id
SQL;

return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery($q)
    ->setParameter('id', 1)
    ->getResult();
```

In both cases the output of the query variable is `SELECT * FROM App\Entity\Invoice WHERE id = :id`.

Note that you must initialize a variable for `HEREDOC`, as it cannot directly evaluate `{Invoice::class}`. That option would definitely be suitable for longer queries (especially since it highlights SQL keywords), while `sprintf` can be utilized for short, straightforward ones.

Comment: OK, so in summary there is no way to do this using DQL. QueryBuilder permits to retrieve the entity automatically, but not using DQL syntax, sadly. At this time, the only way would be replacing the class like your others suggestions. I will wait some days to see if someone else will show up with another idea. Thanks you in all cases.

Comment: @sdespont Query builder internally turns this into DQL and you can fetch what is built using `$dql = $qb->getDql();` if that is what you need. If you specifically want to *write* DQL, then yeah, I'm fresh out of ideas. Maybe someone with more knowledge of Doctrine will come along. You're welcome in any case.

Answer (score -1):

I apologize if you explicitly need DQL, but I haven't seen anyone mention DBAL QueryBuilder.

Here is your query, in Repository class, using DBAL QueryBuilder:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()
->getConnection() //
->createQueryBuilder() // This is different query builder that doesn't automatically assume Entity
->select('i')
->from('invoice', 'i') // Specify the table
->where('i.id = :id') // Rest of the syntax should be similar to DQL but you need to query against table columns, not properties (like in DQL) - for example, in DQL: ... where('firstName = :firstName') ... in DBAL: where('first_name = :firstName')
->setParameter('id', 1)
->execute()->fetchAllAssociative(); // Double check if you can fetch as stdClass
```

In any case, DBAL QueryBuilder is different from Doctrine Query Builder by being closer to  the database layer.

More about DBAL QueryBuilder: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#sql-query-builder

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to use DQL. The reason is because complexes queries with join and nested conditions AND / OR (incuding AND in it) are very hard to write and to read for people not using this syntax every days.